# How do I edit a JSON string in a BLOB field using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, blob

I'm currently working on a project involving editing datatables using PHP, and I have been using phpMyAdmin a lot for the past several weeks. It has recently come to my attention that one of the fields I'm supposed to edit is actually a "BLOB". This BLOB contains a JSON string including the IDs of users. It goes like this:

> `["162","163","164","165","166"..."284","285"]`

The issue I'm having with this is, because my project includes having a form that creates new users, I need to add their IDs to this BLOB... which I'm not sure how I would go about doing that, because I don't know how to edit it using PHP directly.

I have done similar tasks in C before and I'm hoping PHP allows for things like those too, but I have absolutely no idea how. Could anybody provide some insight?

Comment: ___I need to add their IDs to this BLOB___ === Major Database Design ERROR

Comment: Comma seperated lists of id's are a major problem for this and 100 other reasons. You need to look at a database design tutorial before you go any further with this project

Comment: PS A BLOB column is not a file

Comment: Also that structure could be used as a JSON column if you have MySQL5.7+ or can be manipulated using `json_decode()` into a PHP array if you use PHP

Comment: BLOB column isn't a file but rather a column of files, right?
And they seem like a counter-intuitive design decision to me too, at least in the present case... I'll have a look at `json_decode()` as you and Brett suggested

Comment: The `json_decode()` solution worked like a charm! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the data into a PHP array using [`json_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
// $blob is the value from your database
$data = json_decode($blob, TRUE);
```

And then push a new value (or manipulate it however you want), like:

```
$data[] = 123;
```

And then convert it back to a string using [`json_encode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), ready to be saved back into your database:

```
$data = json_encode($data);
// Set the blob field value to $data and save
```

Comment: That worked wonders, thanks a lot!